# Why does my UIButton.titleLabel.text disappear when I place an image in the button?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uibutton, textlabel

I've had this problem before but was able to work around it until now, Basically I'm creating a custom UIbutton setting its image as a uiimage and then the button that has had a label until I implimented the below code now loses its label. I need that label because it is set programatically in code that follows.

```
 NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:kNameOfButtonimage ];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
            [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
```

Any help you could lend would be mucho appreciated.

-nick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I needed to do a:

```
[button setBackroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
```

instead of this:

```
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
```

;)

Comment: I discovered the same applies for titleColor too, i.e this 
`[buttonTemp setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

instead of this:
`buttonTemp.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];`